# pythonのスレッドを使って計算途中の値を監視するプログラムを書いたのですが、while文を終了するには

Tags: python, python3, 非同期

**問題**
threadingを使用して0から100を足すプログラムを2つ立ててその合計値を監視する関数で200%になるまで監視したいのですが、200%になった途端エラーが出力されます。スレッドを使用するプログラムを作成するのは始めてなのでこのような書き方で合っているのか分からないの詳しい方に見て頂きたいと思い質問させて頂きました。

プログラムが最後まで動作するようにしたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

**コード**

```
import time
import threading
import sys

class AddingNumber():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum = 0
    
    def adding(self):
        for i in range(100):
            time.sleep(.1)
            self.sum += 1
    
    def progress(self):
        while True:
            sys.stdout.write('{percent}%\r'.format(percent=self.sum))
        
calculation = AddingNumber()

t2 = threading.Thread(target=calculation.progress)
t2.setDaemon(True) 
t2.start()

for i in range(2):
    t = threading.Thread(target=calculation.adding)
    t.start()
    t.join()

print(calculation.sum)
```

**エラー内容**

```
Fatal Python error: could not acquire lock for <_io.BufferedWriter name='<stdout>'> at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads

Current thread 0x00007fffb20a8380 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: エラーの原因はwhile文が強制的に終了する事でした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

合計値を`stdout`に出力する処理が、`while True:`で無限ループになっていてメインスレッドの終了監視処理(そんなものが可能か？は不明ですが)も無いので、`daemon`設定されていたとしても、メインスレッドが終了して`stdout`が`close`された後、`daemon`スレッドが終了させられる前にも`sys.stdout.write()`処理が走ってしまうのだと思われます。

明示的に監視スレッドを停止させる機能を持たせて、プログラム終了前にそれを呼び出す必要があるでしょう。
以下のような変更が考えられます。####でコメントした所が変更・追加点です。

```
import time
import threading
import sys

class AddingNumber():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum = 0
        self.Loop = True  #### ループ制御用のフラグを設ける
    
    def adding(self):
        for i in range(100):
            time.sleep(.1)
            self.sum += 1
    
    def terminate(self):      #### ループ停止用メソッド追加
        self.Loop = False
    
    def progress(self):
        while self.Loop: #### 無限ループでは無く制御用フラグを見て継続・終了する
            sys.stdout.write('{percent}%\r'.format(percent=self.sum))

calculation = AddingNumber()

t2 = threading.Thread(target=calculation.progress)
t2.setDaemon(True) 
t2.start()

for i in range(2):
    t = threading.Thread(target=calculation.adding)
    t.start()
    t.join()

calculation.terminate() #### 監視スレッド停止指示
t2.join()               #### 監視スレッド終了待ち

print(calculation.sum)
```

---

ちなみに細かい仕組みについてはこちらの記事の懸賞ポイントの付いた回答で解説されているようです。
[Fatal Python error and `BufferedWriter`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45267439/9014308)

---

**コメント対応：**

`def adding(self):`の中の`for i in range(100):`の`range`の値をパラメータ指定したい場合は、以下の記事が参考になるでしょう。
[Pythonのスレッドで引数を渡せなくて躓いた話。](https://meiei.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/12/17/213639)

`def adding(self):`の部分を以下のようにして：

```
def adding(self, count):
    for i in range(count):
        time.sleep(.1)
        self.sum += 1
```

スレッド生成部分を以下のようにすれば良いでしょう(例えば150を指定)：

```
t = threading.Thread(target=calculation.adding, args=(150,))
```

Comment: すいません、とても助かります。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 上記のプログラムを動かして気になった事があるのですが、最後に出力をターミナルに残るようにしたく`print('{percent}#\r'.format(percent=calculation.sum))`を追加したのですが、`200%%`が2つ表示されてしまいます。なので`print(calculation.sum)`とすると`%`が一つとなりいい感じになったのですが、なぜこのような挙動をするのか分からないです。

Comment: それは何時の時点でのプログラムでしょう？ 質問時点のものだと無限ループからの出力とメインの最後の出力が混じった可能性があるかもしれません。

Comment: time.sleep(3)と遅らせても同じ結果でした。

Comment: メインプログラムの最後の`print`の前に改行するだけの`print()`を入れてみて結果がどうなるか試してみては？ 別に新しく質問としてもよいかもしれませんね。

Comment: ループ文の方で`sys.stdout.write('  {percent}%\r'.format(percent=self.sum))`と`percent`の前に空白があるのが原因で上書きされる際に%%の箇所がずれ出力されていたと思われます。

Comment: あと上記のプログラムでfor文の中に`join()`が含まれている箇所があるのですが、この場合そのスレッドが処理を停止するまで次の処理に移れないので、処理は非同期になってないですよね。

Comment: そうですね。加算するスレッドは1度に1個だけしか動作していません。加算と監視は並行で非同期に動作しています。

Comment: 計算も非同期にしたい場合どのようにリファクタリングしたら良いでしょうか？

Comment: その辺はコメントのやり取りでは無く新規に質問を起こした方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 質問を新しく立てました。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/71599/%e3%82%b9%e3%83%ac%e3%83%83%e3%83%89%e3%81%a7%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%a0%e3%81%8c%e9%9d%9e%e5%90%8c%e6%9c%9f%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84